# PIL- animating GIFs, but some frames are black

Tags: tkinter, python-imaging-library, gif

I've been trying to animate images inside a chat program automatically using PIL and Tkinter in Python. Sometimes they work, but most of the time they don't. I will provide images that work and ones that don't

Basically, I am animating the images by calling `ImageTk.PhotoImage` on each image in the GIF sequence, and the animations are run by updating the label widgets with a root.after call. The animation works pretty smoothly

My problem is, though, that most animated GIFs I try running are corrupted, or something. usually the first frame is fine, but the rest are either completely black or full of artifacts.

These are the images:

This one is one of the few that works: 
`http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs42/f/2009/061/d/8/d856ba6223c66ce347c6c814f67d307b.gif`

These ones flash black:

`http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2010/007/c/3/_mekolai__by_Pyritie.gif`
`http://e.deviantart.com/emoticons/s/shakefist.gif`

EDIT: I see no one wants to help me. maybe it's because it's tl;dr. I'll try shortening it

some code:

```
def ExtHandler(self, widget, url): # sorts out what to do with each file extensions
    name = url.split('/')[-1].split('?')[0]
    path = './Storage/Temp/Images/'+name
    try:
        if name.endswith('.gif'):
            img = Image.open(path)
            animation = []
            x = 0
            print name
            while True:
                try:
                    img.seek(x)

                    newpath = './Storage/Temp/Images/{0}__{1}.png'.format(x, name.split('.', 1)[0])
                    img.save(newpath, transparency = img.info['transparency'], format='PNG')

                    newimg = Image.open(path)
                    newimg.load()
                    newimg = newimg.convert('RGB').convert('P', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=255)

                    dur = img.info['duration']
                    if dur < 50: dur = 50
                    newimg = Image.open(newpath)

                    animation.append((PhotoImage2(newimg), dur))
                    x += 1
                except EOFError:
                    break #no more images in the animation!
                except Exception as e:
                    print traceback.format_exc()
                    break
            if len(animation) > 1:
                self.animations[name] = animation

        elif name.endswith('.jpg'):
            img = Image.open(path)
            img = img.convert('RGB').convert('P', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=255)

        elif name.endswith('.png'):
            img = Image.open(path)
            img.load()
            try:
                alpha = img.split()[3]
                img = img.convert('RGB').convert('P', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=255)
                mask = Image.eval(alpha, lambda a: 255 if a <=128 else 0)
                img.paste(255, mask)
            except:
                img = img.convert('RGB').convert('P', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=255)

        height, width = img.size[0], img.size[1]
        if width > 100 or height > 100:
            img = maxSize(img, (100, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS) # resize thumbnails

        self.images[name] = PhotoImage2(img)
        if name in self.animations:
            self.animation(name)
        else:
            self.update_frames(name, self.images[name])
    except:
        print name
        traceback.print_exc()

def animation(self, name):
    if name not in self.animations:
        return
    x = self.animations[name].pop(0)
    self.animations[name].append(x)
    img, time = x

    self.images[name] = img
    self.update_frames(name, self.images[name])
    self.root.after(time, lambda: self.animation(name))
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.. I see them all animated.

I've embedded your links in this answer, so that people don't have to click your links to see the animations.

[image: Works]

[image: Works]

[image]

Note that I'm using chrome as a browser. I'll save this message and see how it looks in Internet explorer and FireFox, and report the results.

...

**update**

Ok, here are the results:

I'm on Windows XP.

- Works with IE8
- Works with Chrome 10.0.648.205
- Works with Chrome 14.0.810.0
- Works with FireFox 5.0

So, I cannot reproduce your problem here. I think it's fairly safe to assume that these animations will work as expected in people's browsers.

Maybe you should add some more information about how you view the animations.

From a technical point of view I don't see a problem, but the animations look sort of cheap, so I'd think twice before adding them to a site, but that's a matter of taste.

**update 2**
Ah, I reread your question. You're not using a browser, but you're creating an application. I'm sure that the problem lies in the libraries that you use.

Maybe you can open the gifs in something like Gif animation workshop or some program like that, to see the difference.. maybe you can re-save them in such a way that they all work?

That's about all I can say to help you for now I'm afraid.

Comment: I am using PIL and Tkinter in Python. Sorry, I didnt realize that when I re-editted my question I deleted that info

Answer (score 0):

This is my working version (for converting the gifs to a series of pngs):

```
import traceback
import Image

class Test:

    def __init__(self):
        self.ExtHandler("", "http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs42/f/2009/061/d/8/d856ba6223c66ce347c6c814f67d307b.gif")
        self.ExtHandler("", "http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2010/007/c/3/_mekolai__by_Pyritie.gif")
        self.ExtHandler("", "http://e.deviantart.com/emoticons/s/shakefist.gif")

    def ExtHandler(self, widget, url): # sorts out what to do with each file extensions
        name = url.split('/')[-1].split('?')[0]
        path = 'C:\\Temp\\'+name
        try:
            if name.endswith('.gif'):
                img = Image.open(path)
                print name
                while True:
                    try:
                        x = img.tell() + 1
                        img.seek(x)

                        newpath = 'C:\\Temp\\{1}_{0}.png'.format(x, name.split('.', 1)[0])
                        img.save(newpath, transparency = img.info['transparency'])
                    except EOFError:
                        break #no more images in the animation!
                    except Exception as e:
                        print traceback.format_exc()
                        break

            elif name.endswith('.jpg'):
                img = Image.open(path)
                img = img.convert('RGB').convert('P', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=255)

            elif name.endswith('.png'):
                img = Image.open(path)
                img.load()
                try:
                    alpha = img.split()[3]
                    img = img.convert('RGB').convert('P', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=255)
                    mask = Image.eval(alpha, lambda a: 255 if a <=128 else 0)
                    img.paste(255, mask)
                except:
                    img = img.convert('RGB').convert('P', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=255)
        except:
            print name
            traceback.print_exc()

Test()
```

I think the solution is
a) seeking with img.tell() + 1
b) saving without the format parameter

In your actual code you probably don't have to cache the gif frames as pngs. Just seek with img.tell() + 1 :)

Comment: I think I found the problem. I was opening the images imediately after saving them, and i think that might have bugged things out on the I/O level. I made it so it will loop twice: once to save everything, and add all the paths and animation durations to a list, and the second loop iterates over that list of paths and opens them. This worked.